# Does Scala have an equivalent to C#'s Global Namespace Alias?

Tags: scala

I have a 3rd party library with a packaged named:

```
abc
```

Containing a class:

```
theirClass
```

Then I have my own library with the following packages:

```
com.me.lib
com.me.lib.abc
```

From the context of a scala file in the com.me.lib package I want to reference the code in the 3rd party library:

```
package com.me.lib
import abc._  // I want this to import the 3rd party lib, not com.me.lib.abc

// use code in the 3rd party lib here
new theirClass
```

In C# this would be easy:

```
namespace com.me.lib
using global::abc
```

How can I achieve this is Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package com.me.lib
import _root_.abc._
```